# Haskell - seperate main = do into blocks

Tags: user-interface, haskell

I want to make a program to jump back to the option part and don't assign a value in to variable "expression"

I tried to make like nested do function:

```
main = do 
...
option = do
```

and then I would call in some case only do "option", but it doesn't seem to work this way and I couldn't find anywhere any different solution. Would someone give an advice, please?

```
main = do
putStrLn "Enter expression:"
expression <- getLine

putStrLn "Enter a number from 1 to 5:"
putStrLn "1. Convert to Postfix"
putStrLn "2. Convert to Prefix"
putStrLn "3. Convert to Binary Expression Tree"
putStrLn "4. Substitution"
putStrLn "5. Evaluate Expression"
choice <- getLine

case (choice) of
    "1" -> putStrLn $ toPostfix expression
    "2" -> putStrLn $ toPrefix expression
    "3" -> print (parse expression)
    "4" -> do { putStrLn "Enter a variable: "
              ; variable <- getLine
              ; putStrLn "Enter a number: " 
              ; number <- getLine
              ; print (sub expression variable number)
              ; print (solvePostfix (toPostfix (sub expression variable number))) }
    "5" -> print (solvePostfix (toPostfix expression))
    otherwise -> putStrLn "This is not a number from 1 to 5!"
```

Comment: There's nothing called `option` in your code. What do you want the `option` function to do exactly?

Comment: I just wanted to loop back before "case" If user enters bad option, so he can enter a new option

Comment: I didnt want to call whole main function again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't completely understand the question but perhaps you are looking for something like this.

```
main = do
  putStrLn "Enter expression:"
  expression <- getLine

  putStrLn "Enter a number from 1 to 5:"
  putStrLn "1. Convert to Postfix"
  putStrLn "2. Convert to Prefix"
  putStrLn "3. Convert to Binary Expression Tree"
  putStrLn "4. Substitution"
  putStrLn "5. Evaluate Expression"
  choice <- getLine

  let option = do 
        { putStrLn "Enter a variable: "
        ; variable <- getLine
        ; putStrLn "Enter a number: " 
        ; number <- getLine
        ; print (sub expression variable number)
        ; print (solvePostfix (toPostfix (sub expression variable number))) }

  case (choice) of
      "1" -> putStrLn $ toPostfix expression
      "2" -> putStrLn $ toPrefix expression
      "3" -> print (parse expression)
      "4" -> option
      "5" -> print (solvePostfix (toPostfix expression))
      otherwise -> putStrLn "This is not a number from 1 to 5!"
```

or, if you want a loop instead:

```
main = do
  putStrLn "Enter expression:"
  expression <- getLine

  let loop = do
        putStrLn "Enter a number from 1 to 5:"
        putStrLn "1. Convert to Postfix"
        putStrLn "2. Convert to Prefix"
        putStrLn "3. Convert to Binary Expression Tree"
        putStrLn "4. Substitution"
        putStrLn "5. Evaluate Expression"
        choice <- getLine

        case (choice) of
          "1" -> putStrLn $ toPostfix expression
          "2" -> putStrLn $ toPrefix expression
          "3" -> print (parse expression)
          "4" -> do
            { putStrLn "Enter a variable: "
            ; variable <- getLine
            ; putStrLn "Enter a number: " 
            ; number <- getLine
            ; print (sub expression variable number)
            ; print (solvePostfix (toPostfix (sub expression variable number))) }
          "5" -> print (solvePostfix (toPostfix expression))
          otherwise -> putStrLn "This is not a number from 1 to 5!"

        loop -- restart loop from start

  -- in main, start loop
  loop
```

This loop could be achieved using the `forever` helper from the library, but it's important to understand the basic recursive solution.

Comment: I wanted to loop back. Thank you. :]